# PHP & MySQL - Notice: Duplicate entry '1-4' for key 'user_id' on line 31

Tags: php, mysql

How can I stop getting the following error below? What do I need to do to stop getting the notice.

```
Notice: Duplicate entry '1-4' for key 'user_id' on line 31
```

Line 31 is.

```
trigger_error(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

MySQL code.

```
$dbc2 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT *
     FROM users_friends
     WHERE (user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "' AND user_id = '" . $user_id . "')
     OR (friend_id = '" . $user_id . "' AND friend_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "')");

if(mysqli_num_rows($dbc2) == 1){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc2)){ 
        if($row['friendship_status'] == 1){
            //do something...
        } else if($row['friendship_status'] == 0){
            //do something...
        }       
    }
} else if(mysqli_num_rows($dbc2) == 0){
    $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO users_friends (user_id, friend_id, date_created)
         VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "', '" . $user_id . "', NOW())");

    if (!$dbc) {
        trigger_error(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        return;
    } else {     
        //do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a UNIQUE or PRIMARY set up on the (user_id, friend_id) pair, reading from the database to see if there's already a line for a given user-friend pair present and then (if it isn't) inserting it.

You have an error in the first part by writing `(user_id = A AND user_id = B) OR (friend_id = A AND friend_id = B)` instead of `(user_id = A AND friend_id = B) OR (friend_id = A AND user_id = B)`. Your version will never return anything (unless the user is friend with himself and you're asking if he is friend with himself). So, your code mistakenly believes the line is absent.

Comment: And now, -2 and still no reason for it. Are you guys trying to coerce me into not downvoting incorrect answers by intentionally downvoting a correct one?

Answer (score 1):

You friendship relationship here seems to be symmetrical.

In this case, you should insert the friends' ids in strict order: say, least `id` first, greatest `id` second.

This will make one record per friendship, not depending on who befriended whom.

Use this query:

```
SELECT  1
FROM    users_friends
WHERE   (user_id, friend_id) = (LEAST($user_id, $SESSION['user_id']), GREATEST($SESSION['user_id'], $user_id))
```

to check the friendship status, and this one:

```
INSERT
INTO    users_friends (user_id, friend_id)
VALUES  (LEAST($user_id, $SESSION['user_id']), GREATEST($SESSION['user_id'], $user_id))
```

to insert a new record.

Answer (score -1):

The message means that there's already a row in the database which has a matching set of unique keys. (i.e.: The user already exists.)

You have a few options:

1. You could either use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) to replace the existing row completely.
2. You could use [INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to update part of the existing row.
3. You could use [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html) ... to ignore the error.

Of these, I'd recommend using the second option.

Comment: How can i just let the user know that there already is a value in the database?

Comment: You could use INSERT IGNORE and then check to see if there's a value in mysqli_insert_id. If there isn't one, there was presumably already a record so you can inform the user.

Comment: can you give an example on how to do this?

Comment: @tireds Sorry, but I'm not going to write your code for you. Read the MySQL page I linked to above and the mysqli_insert_id page in the PHP manual - it should be pretty obvious that you need to: 1. Carry out the INSERT IGNORE. 2. Check to see if there's a value returned from mysqli_insert_id. 3. If there is no value, there was no insert hence the entry already existed.

Comment: first I did not say write my code I asked for an example not write my code.

Comment: @tireds I'd already said what you need to do in the comment above the one you asked for an example in. I'm not sure what more you need in the way of an example. (Me confused.) What you do mean by an example, if you don't mean code?

Comment: @Victor Nicollet - I'd rather not make assumptions about what the user was attempting to do in the code, hence I went down the "why this has happened, how you can deal with it" route. Seems reasonable enough, but I take your point. The downvote seems a bit harsh, but that's your call.

Comment: @middaparka: the "if line exists then do nothing else insert" structure is rather obvious in the code he wrote. While your answer is great if inserting data that might cause a collision, the context of the question is why a collision happens when, by design, it shouldn't. A possible edit (for which I would readily remove the downvote) would be to suggest trying to understand why the collision happens.

Comment: @Victor Nicollet To be honest, if I went down that route I'm not sure how much of the original code would be left. (I'd also rather not make assumptions about the database schema.)

Answer (score -1):

You are inserting into users_friends, but you are using user_id as a key apparently? That means only one friend per user could be entered. I think you actually mean a composite key on (user_id, friend_id).

Comment: No: the error is explicit, there's a collision on value 1-4, which means the user_id *key* is a two-column key.